# Make child to have higher z-index than parent

Tags: html, css, z-index

Basically I'm looking to do this, but this doesn't work. How can I achieve the desired result without having to move it to a different place in the DOM?

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>

#parent {
  z-index: -1
}
#child {
  z-index: 999999;
  position: absolute
}
```

Comment: z-index works on elements on the same DOM tree level with non static position, the question is not clear. Do you want the z-index to be higher for #child? You already did it, do you want the #child element to display on top of the parent? Its already displaying like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `relative` position on the parent, and `absolute` position on the child with offset values all set to `0`.

```
#parent {
  position: relative;
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#child {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: This is no different from my code in any way. You would think it would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Here is the fiddle with what author is trying to do, and your solution does not work. https://jsfiddle.net/s9xvjykq/13/

Answer (score 0):

1.) The parent needs to have `position: relative` (or fixed, or absolute)

2.) The child needs to have `position: absolute` and defined width/height, and/or optionally settings for top/bottom/right/left as desired.

In this simple configuration you don't need any z-index at all - the child is above the parent. In more complex situations you can use z-index.

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  background:red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Child is always on top of the parent by default;
2. `z-index` requires non-static `position` property for proper working.

Comment: So what's the solution? This is more of a comment answer. I need to be able to have the child div be completely over the parent